# When updating an ElementCollection does it trigger the @PostUpdate of the containing object?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an `@ElementCollection Map<User, Long> permissions` in a class.

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "als_permission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "File"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "User")
    @Column(name = "Permission")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<User, Integer> permissions = new HashMap<>();
```

I made some changes on that collection only, and invoke `repo.save(entity)`.  I see the record does get updated, but my `@PostUpdate` handler which is defined in `@EntityListeners` does not appear to be called.

Is there something I have to put to indicate it?  I am thinking I may need to have some sort of `cascade` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: **No.**

I had the same issue came to the conclusion that this is not possible at the moment. Mainly because intended or not implemented yet, see: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/167

For the testing I created a repository to find any event I could consumer for the given purpose: https://github.com/HannesRakete/so-jpa-element-collection-events

### Workaround 1

Add a @Version for optimistic locking on the parent entity.

### Workaround 2

Migrate to another association-type, see https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-query-elementcollection/